# MariaDB / MySQL Combine two tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-order-by, union-all

I have 2 tables tnHeaders and tnData

tnHeaders

| fnIDX | fnDESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | h1 |
| 2 | h2 |
| 3 | h3 |

tnData

| fnIDX | fnHEADER_IDX | fnDESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | d1 |
| 2 | 1 | d2 |
| 3 | 1 | d3 |
| 4 | 2 | d4 |
| 5 | 2 | d5 |
| 6 | 2 | d6 |
| 7 | 3 | d7 |
| 8 | 3 | d8 |
| 9 | 3 | d9 |

and would like to produce this output

| fnOUTPUT |
| --- |
| h1 |
| d1 |
| d2 |
| d3 |
| h2 |
| d4 |
| d5 |
| d6 |
| h3 |
| d7 |
| d8 |
| d9 |

I can do this in code no problem, but how can I do this in SQL? (Make the server work)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UNION ALL` for the descriptions of both tables and sort the results in such a way that headers are on top of their data:

```
SELECT fnOUTPUT
FROM (
  SELECT fnDESCRIPTION fnOUTPUT, fnIDX header_index, 1 is_header FROM tnHeaders
  UNION ALL
  SELECT fnDESCRIPTION, fnHEADER_IDX, 0 FROM tnData
) t
ORDER BY header_index, is_header DESC, fnOUTPUT;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e3a942a22e2548001d8dbd32cc92057).

Comment: Fast and works. Thanks.